# How do I stop my void Start from acting like a void Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem where I want to addForce to a 2D object only in the start in a random direction but the object adds the force in occurring periods.

```
public float RandomX;
public float RandomY;
public Rigidbody2D Rb;

void Start()
{
    RandomPosition ();
}

void RandomPosition()
{
   RandomX = Random.Range(-2f,2f);
   RandomY = Random.Range(-2f,2f);

   Rb.AddForce(new Vector2 (RandomX,RandomY), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
   Invoke("RandomPosition",1.5f);
}
```

I have no idea what I have done wrong nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Start` itself but you are letting your method call itself again after 1.5 seconds using [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html).

If this isn't what you want but rather just have it called by `Start` **once** then just remove that recursive call to

```
Invoke("RandomPosition",1.5f);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to move this to its own method and apply in FixedUpdate()

Rb.AddForce(new Vector2 (RandomX,RandomY), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

I think Physics calculations are only done in FixedUpdate...?